# TopologyException when using turf.intersect

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I'm getting the following error when using turf.intersect with a specific polygon:
"TopologyException" "found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING ( -0.140733 51.505327, -0.141097 51.505689 ) and LINESTRING ( -0.141136 51.505674, -0.141068 51.5057 )"

Here is the polygon with the point that's causing the issue:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -0.144414,
              51.5057787
            ],
            [
              -0.1444,
              51.5057669
            ],
            [
              -0.1444174,
              51.5057565
            ],
            [
              -0.1444375,
              51.5057437
            ],
            [
              -0.1444486,
              51.5057591
            ],
            [
              -0.1448395,
              51.5055465
            ],
            [
              -0.1456195,
              51.5051519
            ],
            [
              -0.1461211,
              51.5048921
            ],
            [
              -0.1467341,
              51.5045993
            ],
            [
              -0.1472694,
              51.5042539
            ],
            [
              -0.147728,
              51.5039184
            ],
            [
              -0.1485316,
              51.5035408
            ],
            [
              -0.1485702,
              51.5035234
            ],
            [
              -0.1488964,
              51.503376
            ],
            [
              -0.1489081,
              51.5033859
            ],
            [
              -0.1491678,
              51.503267
            ],
            [
              -0.1491573,
              51.5032582
            ],
            [
              -0.1494585,
              51.5031342
            ],
            [
              -0.1495505,
              51.5031388
            ],
            [
              -0.1495754,
              51.503085
            ],
            [
              -0.1496124,
              51.5026853
            ],
            [
              -0.1495618,
              51.5026316
            ],
            [
              -0.1495053,
              51.5025839
            ],
            [
              -0.1490356,
              51.5025596
            ],
            [
              -0.1480816,
              51.5025194
            ],
            [
              -0.1464951,
              51.5024587
            ],
            [
              -0.1453418,
              51.5023882
            ],
            [
              -0.1444299,
              51.5023513
            ],
            [
              -0.1424233,
              51.502272
            ],
            [
              -0.1420358,
              51.5022744
            ],
            [
              -0.1416246,
              51.5022811
            ],
            [
              -0.1414344,
              51.5022758
            ],
            [
              -0.14113,
              51.5023094
            ],
            [
              -0.1409441,
              51.50233
            ],
            [
              -0.1412107,
              51.5026049
            ],
            [
              -0.1407386,
              51.5026799
            ],
            [
              -0.1402814,
              51.5026536
            ],
            [
              -0.1398146,
              51.5025228
            ],
            [
              -0.1396726,
              51.5024475
            ],
            [
              -0.1395941,
              51.5023923
            ],
            [
              -0.1394956,
              51.5024312
            ],
            [
              -0.1393765,
              51.5024829
            ],
            [
              -0.1388305,
              51.502698
            ],
            [
              -0.1387333,
              51.5027403
            ],
            [
              -0.1387835,
              51.5027906
            ],
            [
              -0.1392711,
              51.5032406
            ],
            [
              -0.139465,
              51.503466
            ],
            [
              -0.1399479,
              51.5039078
            ],
            [
              -0.1403315,
              51.504302
            ],
            [
              -0.1407059,
              51.5046814
            ],
            [
              -0.1402579,
              51.5048283
            ],
            [
              -0.1407332,
              51.5053265
            ],
            [
              -0.1410967,
              51.5056887
            ],
            [
              -0.1410841,
              51.5056711
            ],
            [
              -0.1411158,
              51.5056574
            ],
            [
              -0.1411356,
              51.5056744
            ],
            [
              -0.141068,
              51.5057001
            ],
            [
              -0.1411549,
              51.5058139
            ],
            [
              -0.1412316,
              51.5057886
            ],
            [
              -0.1412437,
              51.5058054
            ],
            [
              -0.1411693,
              51.5058326
            ],
            [
              -0.1411811,
              51.5058428
            ],
            [
              -0.1412021,
              51.5058461
            ],
            [
              -0.1412326,
              51.5058618
            ],
            [
              -0.1412584,
              51.5058575
            ],
            [
              -0.1413349,
              51.5059475
            ],
            [
              -0.1413677,
              51.5059833
            ],
            [
              -0.1413704,
              51.5060066
            ],
            [
              -0.1413538,
              51.506016
            ],
            [
              -0.1413494,
              51.5060451
            ],
            [
              -0.1414301,
              51.5061301
            ],
            [
              -0.1414221,
              51.5061562
            ],
            [
              -0.1414889,
              51.5062259
            ],
            [
              -0.1415374,
              51.5062089
            ],
            [
              -0.1415669,
              51.506238
            ],
            [
              -0.1415172,
              51.5062553
            ],
            [
              -0.141583,
              51.506326
            ],
            [
              -0.1416228,
              51.5063353
            ],
            [
              -0.1416919,
              51.5064173
            ],
            [
              -0.1416845,
              51.5064298
            ],
            [
              -0.1416341,
              51.5064488
            ],
            [
              -0.1416636,
              51.5064833
            ],
            [
              -0.1416771,
              51.5064797
            ],
            [
              -0.1416892,
              51.5064881
            ],
            [
              -0.1418973,
              51.5064092
            ],
            [
              -0.1419091,
              51.5064204
            ],
            [
              -0.141691,
              51.5065052
            ],
            [
              -0.1417355,
              51.5065528
            ],
            [
              -0.1417624,
              51.5065417
            ],
            [
              -0.1417862,
              51.506569
            ],
            [
              -0.141812,
              51.5065727
            ],
            [
              -0.141838,
              51.5065954
            ],
            [
              -0.1418271,
              51.5066109
            ],
            [
              -0.1418623,
              51.5066435
            ],
            [
              -0.1418837,
              51.5066417
            ],
            [
              -0.1419093,
              51.5066617
            ],
            [
              -0.1419035,
              51.5066764
            ],
            [
              -0.1419137,
              51.5066845
            ],
            [
              -0.1419323,
              51.506686
            ],
            [
              -0.1419469,
              51.5067007
            ],
            [
              -0.1419413,
              51.5067104
            ],
            [
              -0.1419583,
              51.5067201
            ],
            [
              -0.1421823,
              51.5066524
            ],
            [
              -0.1422288,
              51.5066342
            ],
            [
              -0.1423373,
              51.5067681
            ],
            [
              -0.1430385,
              51.5064228
            ],
            [
              -0.143099,
              51.5064704
            ],
            [
              -0.1439141,
              51.5060467
            ],
            [
              -0.144414,
              51.5057787
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.14109693591549397,
          51.5056889362676
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried using cleanCoords and checking for intersections with kinks, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I managed to make it work:

```
var options = {tolerance: 0.0001, highQuality: true};
poly = turf.cleanCoords(turf.simplify(poly, options));
```

I also checked for kinks, and divided the polygon if it returned true:

```
var kinks = turf.kinks(poly);
if (kinks.features.length){
  polys = turf.unkinkPolygon(poly);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer to this question

> [What does the following error mean: TopologyException: found non-nonded intersection between LINESTRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662448/what-does-the-following-error-mean-topologyexception-found-non-nonded-intersec)

I have found this solotion to be feasible, as well:

```
let myWorkingPolygon = turf.buffer(errorThrowingPolygon, 0, {units:"meters"});
```

Buffer calculates a buffer around the given feature (but here with buffer size 0), find more info here: https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer